# How to save date in 'YYYY/MM/DD' format in Oracle despite NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set as 'DD-MON-YY'

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

Currently in my database

```
nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YY'
```

But I want to save date in YYYY/DD/MM format .
Is it possible to save data in YYYY/DD/MM format because when I do

```
insert into tab1(name) values to_date(sysdate,'YYYY/DD/MM') ;
```

it shows below error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
*Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
*Action:   None.
```

Altering the session works ,for eg

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY/DD/MM' ;
insert into tab1(name) values to_date(sysdate) ;

select * from tab1;   
2017/31/05
```

Is there any way to save the data without altering session .so that data gets saved in table in 'YYYY/MM/DD' format instead of NLS_DATE_FORMAT ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Dates are stored in no particular format. You use a format-string to convert a string literal to a value of `date` data type. But it doesn't mean that a date will be stored in that format, you just instruct Oracle to treat it as a date. No more, no less. You use formatting to display a value of date data type in a format you desire. Dates will be stored as fixed-length fields of seven bytes in Oracle's internal format no matter what format string you specify when converting a string literal to a value of `date` data type.

Comment: `sysdate` is already a date. `TO_CHAR()` is used to convert from **string**, thus it doesn't work. What you're trying to do does not make much sense, `insert into tab1(name) values (sysdate)` is more than enough.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for the answer . So I can only retrieve the value in 'YYYY/MM/DD' using to_date and I cant save it in this format .Correct me if I have misinterpreted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### you can not save date format in date column.

you can write your date like `to_char(your_date,'YYYY/DD/MM')` to column which data type is `varchar`.

when you read data you can use `to_date` function like `to_date(your_value,'YYYY/DD/MM')`

Answer (score 0):

DATE and TIMESTAMP columns don't have any specific format. You can display your own format. you want to set default format means you can set NLS setting.